# How to add EditText in ListView multiple choice type

Tags: android

I have inside LinearLayout ListView with multiple select choice(all strings). How to add on last position in ListView EditText. I have used ArrayAdapter to fill list with strings. How to add that field ?

Comment: means you want to have EditText inside every listview items?

Answer (score 0):

Create an own layout for the items of listview and inflate it. Here an example how to inflate it:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        // Inflate a new View every time a new row requires one.
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.youritemview, parent, false);
    }
    ...
}
```